# Combine two text files in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have a text file (FILE_A.txt) with this content:

```
Content1
Content2
Content3
```

And other text file (FILE_B.txt) with this content:

```
A[#]
B[#]
C[#]
```

I would like to combine FILE_A.txt and FILE_B.txt in other file (FILE_C.txt) in this way:

```
A[Content1]
B[Content2]
C[Content3]
```

How could I make this using bash shell in linux (sed, cut, grep, etc)?

Comment: I've tried again with diferents contents for FILE_A and FILE_B, and I don't know why it doesn't works. File_B.txt now has "something(#,@);" and File_A.txt has "__OtherTexts". When I try to combine the two files with dogbane method, it copies the content of each line at the end of the lines contained in FILE_B.txt. Any ideas?

Comment: With my new issue, the ghoti method works fine for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we go.

```
# awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next;} sub(/#/,a[FNR])' FILE_A.txt FILE_B.txt
A[Content1]
B[Content2]
C[Content3]
```

**How does this work?**

- `NR==FNR` - causes the following statements to be run if the record number matches the FILE record number - that is, we are currently reading only the firs tfile.
- `{a[NR]=$0;next;}` - Store values from the first file in an array.
- `sub(/#/,a[FNR])` - Once we're in the second file, substitute `#` for the matching value stored from the first file.  Note that this isn't inside curly brackets, so it's being evaluated as a condition.  If the `sub()` statement succeeds, the current line is printed.

Comment: No problem, Cesar.  The advantage of this also is that because we're using `sub()` to replace a substring, this solution basically makes the lines of `FILE_A.txt` into a template for the data in `FILE_B.txt`.  If your requirements become more complex than your sample data, this may be preferable to handling the output from `paste`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `paste` and `sed` as follows:

```
$ paste File_B.txt File_A.txt | sed 's/#]\s*\(.*$\)/\1]/g'
A[Content1]
B[Content2]
C[Content3]
```

Comment: Works in Linux, but the `\s` makes it non-portable.  Won't work in BSD, OSX, Solaris, etc, unless you've installed GNU sed.

Comment: @ghoti That's easily fixed. You can change the `paste` command to use a specific delimiter of your choice (using the `-d` option) and then use the same delimiter in the `sed` command instead of the `\s*`.

Answer (score 2):

The following reads both files concurrently, one line at a time, and store the lines in `$value` and `$template`. We then use bash's variable substring replacement to replace `#` within `$template` with the  contents of `$value`.

```
exec 6<"FILE_B.txt"  # open file for reading and assign file descriptor 6

while read -r value; do  # loop through FILE_A.txt, storing each line as $value
  read -r template <&6   # read a line from FILE_B.txt, store as $template
  echo ${template/\#/$value}  # replace value into the template in place of `#`
done <"FILE_A.txt"

exec 6<&-  # close input file descriptor 6
```

Comment: Complex but very educational. Thanks for your answer.